# Multiplication whole numbers as classes

Tags: number-theory

Why can you define the multiplication of whole numbers as classes such that for every whole number  [a1,b1]  <-> a1-b1
The multiplication of 2 whole numbers is
[a1, b1] *[a2, b2] = A1A2 + b1b2, a1b2 + b1a2,

If a1,b1 = a1-b1, shouldn't it be
A1A2 + b1b2, a1b2 - b1a2.

Sorry I wrote this on a smartphone.

Comment: If you're defining the integers by quotienting sets of ordered pairs $(a_1,b_1)$ according to their difference (so every integer is a difference $a_1-b_1$), then the product of two integers $(a_1 -b_1)(a_2-b_2)$ is $a_1 a_2 -a_1 b_2 - a_2b_1 + b_1b_2$, simplifying to  $(a_1a_2 + b_1b_2) - (a_1b_2 + a_2b_1)$, as you suggested. I'm not sure what the origin of your question is, did you see it defined otherwise somewhere?

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Long comemnt*

See [Construction of Integers from Natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction) :

> the intuition is that $(a,b)$ stands for the result of subtracting $b$ from $a$.

Thus, $[(a_1,b_1)] \times [(a_2,b_2)] =_{def} [(a_1 a_2+ b_1 b_2,a_1 b_2+a_2b_1)]$.

According to the above comment, we have to read $(a_1 a_2+ b_1 b_2,a_1 b_2+a_2b_1)$ as $(a_1 a_2+ b_1 b_2)-(a_1 b_2+a_2b_1)$ and this is consistent with $(a_1-b_1) \times (a_2-b_2)$.

Comment: Thank you, got it, really good answer and much appreciated!